# R rbind a dataframe of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rbind

How is it possible to concatenate a dataframe that contains one or more data.frames among its columns. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
df$df <- data.frame(a=1:3)  
rbind( df, df)
```

> Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) :
>   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed In addition: Warning message:
>   non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list(df,df))
```

> Error: Argument 2 can't be a list containing data frames

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: @ANG expected result is equivalent to:  df <- data.frame( a= c(1:3, 1:3)); df$df <- data.frame( a = c(1:3, 1:3))

Comment: The way you're defining it, `df$a` has length 3 but `df$df` has length 1, is that right?

Comment: @cwthom length(df$df) == 1, nrow(df$df) == 3.

Comment: But I think your example is hiding that this isn't really allowed - if you have instead `df$df <- data.frame(a = 1:4)` you'll get an error. So your structure is a special case - is that intended?

Comment: @cwthom of course I intended for length(df$a) == length(df$df$a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be not another `data.frame` within a data frame, but the non-unique `rownames` in the result. If you made sure that rownames are unique after rbind - it should work:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(a=1:3)
df1$df <- data.frame(a=1:3, row.names=letters[1:3])
df2$df <- data.frame(a=1:3, row.names=LETTERS[1:3])

> res <- rbind(df1, df2)
> res
  a a
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 1 1
5 2 2
6 3 3

> res$df
  a
a 1
b 2
c 3
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

The problem seems to be that `rbind` adjusts the rownames for the two data.frames being merged, but does not adjust the rownames for data.frames within data.frames.

Comment: Nice workaround. How would you scale this up for n dataframes, each with approximately m rows, where n and m are arbitrarily large? My idea is `row.names(df.list[[n]]$df) <- paste( letters[n], 1:nrow(df.list[[n]]))`, but it doesn't scale beyond `n==26`.

Comment: I would maybe use `make.unique`: `row.names(df.list[[n]]$df) <- make.unique(rep(paste0("df", n), nrow(df.list[[n]])))`

Comment: Basically this would create a unique id for each dataframe based on their number (like "df1" for n=1). then repeat it as many times as there are rows `rep()`, then make all of those unique by adding additional numbers `make.unique()`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I will wait a couple of days to accept your answer, in case there's a good solution that doesn't require modifying the dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to `rep`licate `df` twice (or more) instead of `rbind`-ing it; this will automatically create non duplicated `row.names`. Try this:

```
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 2), ]
# output
    a a
1   1 1
2   2 2
3   3 3
1.1 1 1
2.1 2 2
3.1 3 3
```

The same process using `dplyr` will give you more interesting `row.names`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% slice(rep(row_number(), 2))
# output
  a a
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 1 1
5 2 2
6 3 3
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it doesn't seem to apply in the general case of `rbind( df1, df2)` ( assuming `!identical(df1, df2)`)

Answer (score 1):

We may `list` the data frames, then using `mapply` to handle column types differently: `stack` for vectors and `do.call(rbind)` for `data.frame`s.

```
L <- mget(ls(pattern="df\\."))  # or list(df.1, df.2, df.3)
res <- data.frame(a=stack(mapply(`[`, L, 1))[[1]])
res$df <- do.call(rbind, mapply(`[`, L, 2))
res
#   a a
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 4 4 4
# 5 5 5
# 6 6 6
# 7 7 7
# 8 8 8
# 9 9 9
str(res)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ a : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# $ df:'data.frame':    9 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ a: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

***Data***

```
df.1 <- structure(list(a = 1:3, df = structure(list(a = 1:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
df.2 <- structure(list(a = 4:6, df = structure(list(a = 4:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
df.3 <- structure(list(a = 7:9, df = structure(list(a = 7:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```